# Connect to rest API with Meteor

Tags: rest, authentication, meteor

I want to connect to rest API with auth in Meteor but when I run through their docs cant see anything stuff for connecting to rest API. All I can see it that the HTTP request. So, I tried using it. I need to connect to this:

```
 URL: http://lpgp-dev.mrkt.it/test/oauth/rest/testview2
 key: 'mykey'
secret: 'my secret'
```

For now I have this lines of code:

from server:

```js
Meteor.methods({
 getArticles: function () {

  check(q, String);
  this.unblock();
  try {
    var result = HTTP.call("GET", "http://lpgp-dev.mrkt.it/test/oauth/rest/testview2",
                       {params: {key: 's86MopNFA6pwmBXQoEw8k5yBVAVjN8vz', secret: 'cKC2tpXP3ZRQvqAsobCPeK2jB4kjsDos'}});
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    // Got a network error, time-out or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
    return false;
  }
 } 
});
```

from client which I called the method:

```js
var getResponse = function(){

Meteor.call('getArticles', function (error, result) {

    if (!error) {
        var res = JSON.parse(result.content);
        /*var _res = _(res.response.docs).toArray();*/
        /*Session.set('numCount', res.response.numFound);
        Session.set('news', _res);*/
        console.log(res);
    }else{
        console.log(error);
    }

});
```

}

When I run it return this error:

```
errorClass: Internal server error [500] of undefined
```

hope you can help me. Thanks...

Comment: where is the variable `q` set that you are checking? Are you sure the error stems from the HTTP call? Have you tried that same call with `curl`?

Comment: Actually the call works, just it needs to use auth, on that function its purely an http request... 
Also, the q variable for check was not supposed to be in there. Just deleted the check function since I didn't used any params there.

Comment: can you print the exception on the server? Just add `console.log(e, e.stack, e.message)` in the catch and see what the error is.

Comment: Yes, When I log it on console, it returns that the function hits their site, Its just it don't have permission since I did not able to implement an auth client. The log on console shows 'user must be login' which the message return my their site for not authenticated user.

Comment: What I am having troubled now is how to implement an auth2 in meteor..

Comment: do you mean oauth2? does it work with curl? Can you show a curl call that works? then we can help you get it done in meteor

Comment: protected static function httpRequest($postData){


  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "http://lpgp-dev.mrkt.it/test/oauth/rest/testview2",,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,

  ));

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $output;
 }


    public static function getArticles($key, $secret) {

  $uri = "users";
  $postData = "key={$key}&secret={$secret}";

  return UserAPI::httpRequest($postData);
 }

That also works on browser API test

Comment: Sorry for the code, cant format it same as above code. :(

Comment: The thing thee is that its needs to have a oauth client as how it will be authenticated but, thats something I didn't get for my research.